# Correctly Marshal String from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I'm currently working on a .NET Framework 4.7.2 application. I need to use some business logic from a native *unmanaged* C++ DLL. No Common Language Runtime allowed in my project.

I try to send a string from my C# to my C++ back and forth. It seems to work fine, I can send a string to the DLL and I get a result. Nevertheless, I encounter an error if I send a longer string from C# to C++ e.g.: *"fourtytwo" results in "f"*, the first letter only gets returned. It should actually return "fourtytwo".

My C# coding looks like this:

```
var test = TestProxy.Wrapper_Create("test");

// string
var pc = TestProxy.TryString(test, "fourtytwo");
var c = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pc); // problem: results in "f" instead of "fourtytwo"
```

My Marshaling definition in C# looks like this:

```
public static class TestProxy
{
   private const string coreDLL = "test.core.dll";

   [DllImport(coreDLL, EntryPoint = "?TryString@TestClass@@XXX@X", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
   public static extern IntPtr TryString(IntPtr instance, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]string n);

}
```

My C++ looks like this:

The header file:

```
#ifdef TESTCORE_EXPORTS
#define TESTCORE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

#pragma once

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C"
{
    class TESTCORE_API TestClass
    {
    private:
        char* name;
    public:
        TestClass(char*);
        char* TryString(char*);
    };

    TESTCORE_API TestClass* Wrapper_Create(char* name);
}
```

The implementation in C++ looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "TestCore.h"

TestClass::TestClass(char* n) 
{
    name = n;
}

char* TestClass::TryString(char* n)
{
    return n; // Something goes wrong here, only "f" returned instead of "fourtytwo"
}

extern "C"
{
    POMCORE_API TestClass * Wrapper_Create(char* name)
    {
        return new TestClass(name);
    }

    POMCORE_API char* TryString(TestClass * instance, char* n) 
    {
        if (instance != NULL)
        {
            return instance->TryString(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know how to correctly marshal a string from C# to C++ and back?

Thank you!

Comment: The significant  difference you should notice is that C# string representation is basically `bstr_t` style and not nul terminated strings as usual in c. There are myriad of examples to find how to marshal these string styles from c# to c++properly  though.

Comment: thanks, actually I only wonder why I get returned from C++ in my C# only 1 letter instead of the whole phrase. Do you have an idea?